# <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes> is not working in SE

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, persistence.xml

I am using eclipselink as JPA provider and needs to keep entities in a jar file. All jar entities are annotated with @Entity.I tried  false and true but it didn't auto detect the entities. I don't want to write all classes  in persistence.xml. Please suggest.

Comment: how have you packaged your entities and your persistence.xml.. where is the persistence.xml in relation to the jar and entity classes?  The persistence.xml should be in a META-INF directory in with the class files.

Comment: @Chris It is packaged in the META-INF directory in with the class files.

Comment: Check that you don't have another one somewhere else on the classpath that might be being picked up.

Answer (score 2):

It is not expected to work in Java SE environment. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> To insure the portability of a Java SE application, it is necessary to
>   explicitly list the managed persistence classes that are included in
>   the persistence unit using the class element ofthe persistence.xml
>   file.